# Postgres - change this string to a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone know how to change a string '22AB1113' to a date? Ideally, I want that string to read '2022-11-13' as the output.

Another example: For the string '22AB0204' I'd actually like this to have '2023-02-04' as the output and NOT '2022-02-04'. The string applies to the year 2023, NOT 2022.

Thanks so much for everyone's help!

```
with fq as (
select 
distinct(replace(bc.sale_name,'22AB','')) as "Date",
sum(bc.num_beds) as "Number of Beds"
from bed_count bc
where (sale_name ilike '%22AB%')
group by 1
order by "Date"
)
select
case
    when fq."Date"::int >= 500 then concat('2022-',fq."Date"::int)
    when fq."Date" NOT ILIKE '0%' then concat('2022-',fq."Date")
    else concat('2023-',fq."Date")
    end as "Date",
fq."Number of Beds"
from fq
```

Comment: In short, what's the logic to determine whether the year is 2022 or 2023? For strings greater or equal to '0500' it is 2022 otherwise 2023?

Comment: Yes exactly! >= 0500 would be the year 2022 and < 0500 would be 2023

Comment: `select to_char(to_date('22AB1113', 'YYABMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 2022-11-13` and for `<500` `select to_char(to_date('22AB1113', 'YYABMMDD') + interval '1 year', 'YYYY-MM-DD');  2023-11-13`

Answer (score 0):

Shall be simple using `format` and `case`.

```sql
with fq as ( ... )
select format(
   '%s-%s-%s',
   case when "Date" > '0500' then '2022' else '2023' end, 
   substr("Date", 1, 2), 
   substr("Date", 3, 2)
 ) as "Date",
 "Number of Beds"
from fq;
```

You might wish to cast the date text to proper `date` format too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - this worked!! Thank you so much!!! :)